# Use of const in strict mode (Node.js and Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have seen this question asked many times around here, but none of the solutions seem to fit my case.

I am using Node.js to access a MongoDB database. I am using Mongoose library. All on Ubuntu 14.04.

When trying to run "nodejs myfile.js" I get this error:

```
const deprecationWarning = 'The `MONGOOSE_DRIVER_PATH` global property is ' 
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

The main solution I found is upgrading Node.js with this commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

but the result after is the same.

Also tried to run it with 'harmony' flag:

```
nodejs --harmony myfile.js
```

...but I still get similar errors like:

```
for (const key of ['Schema', 'model']) {
               ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My dependencies in package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "~5.7.5"
}
```

And my Node.js version is v0.10.25

It seems I don't get to find the correct combination of packages or I am doing something else wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `nodejs --harmony myfile.js"` is there a quote at the end?

Comment: my mistake, sorry. I edited to remove

Comment: Have you tried to add `use strict` in your file at the very top? And try to use `let` in loop.

Comment: `const in for-of loop` is not supported in your version of node. Not even behind the `--harmony` flag. [Compatibility table](https://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-const-for-of-loop-iteration-scope--strict-mode-)

Comment: If you want to use iterator protocol you need to either update your version of node (recommended) or use transpiler (say babel) to transpile your code to ES5 version.

Comment: Trying to use     `"use strict;"` at the very top of `myfile.js` is not making the difference. And it is already set in     `/root/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/index.js` file. Trying to modify the code inside Mongoose files may not be the best idea perhaps (as I'm not sure what I am doing), may be better upgrading Node.js... but seems it is not working

Comment: @YuryTarabanko how can I upgrade if what I posted is not working? To wich version should I upgrade?

Comment: @jaume Visit https://nodejs.org/en/ Select current version. Follow instructions for your OS.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, thanks :) . Now I have the version `v10.16.3` for "node" (installed from its website) and the version `v0.10.25` for "nodejs" (that I see I installed with `apt-get install nodejs` ). Now I can run the code with `node myfile.js`. Not sure what is the difference though (any further explanation would be great), but you found the solution. If you post it as an answer I can validate it.

Comment: "Not sure what is the difference though" hmm `v10.x` is ten versions ahead of `v0.10.x` thats a huge difference. Like 4 years of active development.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I mean between "nodejs" and "node" programs. Notice that upgrading nodejs v.0.x didn't drive to node v10.x ... they seem to be different programs